# Does Azure set and expose the `CI` environment variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

There's a [5 year old Github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/1949) that asks for Azure to set the conventional `CI` environment variable to true, so that it can be used by scripts relying on this convention.

Is `env.CI` set today?

Comment: Where is `CI` documented/described/acknowledged as a convention or de facto standard? What tools and services support `CI`? The GitHub issue was closed because it was filed in the wrong place. I don't find that a feature request was ever submitted in the 'right' place. If a feature request were created and if the case were to be made that this is a common convention, more than just CircleCI and Travis should be cited.

Comment: GitHub Actions defines `CI=true` and `GITHUB_ACTIONS=true` which follows the CircleCI and Travis pattern. Since GitHub is owned by Microsoft that's an important example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as @JonathanDodds mentions, Azure Pipelines doesn't set an environment variable `CI`, [it sets a whole bunch of variables by default and the official variable to detect Azure Pipelines is `TF_BUILD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

[There are many different environment variables which are set by all of the different CI tools. The `ci-info` project is a good source](https://github.com/watson/ci-info) to see what's defined by who.

There are a few tricks though:

### Set a pipeline variable

Every pipeline variable you set is automatically also turned into an environment variable, so you can create a variable in the Variables panel:

[image: Create CI variable in variables panel]

Or in your YAML file.

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  CI: true

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
```

### Add it to the `.env` file of a self-hosted agent

If you're using a self-hosted agent, you can add a `.env` file in the root of the agent's installation (next to the `config.cmd`).  Every variable defined in there is automatically set on any job that targets that agent.

```
C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\jessehouwing>dir /b
bin
config.cmd
externals
run.cmd
_diag
_work

C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\jessehouwing>echo CI=true >> .env

C:\AzureDevOpsAgents\jessehouwing>run.cmd
```

### Use a Pipeline Decorator

[You can probably create a custom Pipeline Decorator extension that injects a piece of YAML into every pipeline in your Azure DevOps instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Very useful additional info, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As of the date of this question, it appears that Azure DevOps services doesn't define or expose a `CI` variable.

The `TF_BUILD` variable will be defined and set to true for scripts running within an Azure Pipeline. This is the equivalent of the `CI` variable. To be portable, a script could test for either `CI` or `TF_BUILD`.

(Azure DevOps was previously known as Team Foundation Server/Services (TFS), hence the TF in `TF_BUILD`.)

Comment: I tested with a PowerShell script running `dir env:` to ensure this is not just a documentation issue.